# I am receiving a segmentation fault error yet do not understand where the segmentation fault is occuring

Tags: c++

I believe the error is occurring somewhere before line 16, the first cout statement is not shown when ran after compiling. My most confusing point is that not even the first cout statement in main is shown. Could the error have started somewhere that i have not noticed or is it somewhere in my include statements? I am at a loss here because it seems very odd to have a seg fault before any code is truly ran especially in main.

```
      2 #include<iostream>
      3 #include<iomanip>
      4 #include<sstream>
      5 #include<fstream>
      6 using namespace std;
      8 void Show_Menu(int);
      9 string* getScreen(int);
     13
     14 int main()
     15 {
     16     cout <<"Thank You for Choosing Taco Bell";
     17     string* menu = nullptr;
     18     menu = getScreen(1);
     19     int input = 1;
     20     Show_Menu(input);
     21     return 0;
     22 };
     23
     24 string* getScreen( int input)
     25 {
     26     string taco_burrito[] = {"Tacos and Burritos","Beef_Burrito_Supreme", "Bean_Burrito", "Beefy_Five_Layer_Burrito", "Shredded_Chicken_Burrito", "Seven_Layer_Burrito", "Taco", "Soft_ta    co", "Shredded_Chicken_Soft_Taco", "Taco_Supreme", "Soft_Taco_Supreme", "Grilled_Steak_Soft_Taco", "Nacho_Cheese_Doritos_Locos_Taco" };
     27     string special_items[] = {"Special Items","Cheesy_Roll_Up", "Mexican_Pizza", "Chicken_Quesadilla", "Beef_Chalupa", "Chicken_Power_Bowl", "Cheesy_Gordita_Crunch", "Crunchwrap_Supreme    ", "Beef_Quesarito", "Beefy_Nacho_Griller", "Fiesta_Taco_Salad"};
     28     string nacho_sides_desserts[] = {"Nachos And Desserts","Chips_And_Nacho_Cheese", "Chips_And_Guacamole", "Nachos_Supreme", "Nachos_Bell_Grande", "Chips_And_Pico", "Pintos_And_cheese"    , "Fiesta_Potatos", "Black_Beans_And_Rice", "Black_Beans", "Rice", "Cinnamon_Twist", "Cinnabon_Two_Pack", "Cinnabon_Twelve_Pack"};
     29     string dollar_cravings[] = { "Dollar Cravings","Beefy_Frito_Burrito", "Cheesy_Bean_Rice", "Spicy_Potato_Soft_Taco", "Shredded_Chicken_Quesadilla_Melt", "Spicy_Tostada", "Cheesy_Roll    _Up", "Triple_Layer_Nachos", "Cinnamon_Twist", "Cinnabon_Two_Pack"};
     30         switch(input){
     31             case 1:
     32                 return taco_burrito;
     33                 break;
     34             case 2:
     35                 return special_items;
     36                 break;
     37             case 3:
     38                 return nacho_sides_desserts;
     39                 break;
     40             case 4:
     41                 return dollar_cravings;
     42             default:
     43                 cout << "Invalid Entry" <<endl;
     44             }
     45 };
     46
     47 void Show_Menu(int input = 1)
     48 {
     49     string* screen;
     50     screen = getScreen(input);
     51     cout <<"Current Screen is: " << screen[0] << endl;
     52     int size;
     53     size = sizeof(screen);
     54     for(int i =1; i < size; i++)
     55     {
     56         cout << i << ". " << screen[i] << endl;
     57     }
     58 };
```

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable that is about to be destructed is pretty suspect.

Comment: You won't see that output unless you flush the output buffer; the easiest way is with `cout<<endl`.

Comment: Unrelated: the line numbers are an easy way to mark line 16, but they are a pain in the neck if the code must be copied into a text file and compiled to more closely inspect a difficult problem. Prefer to mark the line in question with a comment over adding line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Couple issues:

- `cout` buffers its output.  That means that the error is likely occurring after the first `cout` statement, but because `cout` has not yet been flushed to the screen, you don't see it.  If you want `cout` to immediately print to the screen, then you should end the line with `<< std::endl`.  Otherwise, use `cerr`, which does not buffer output and will automatically print to the screen.
- As @Eljay reported, `getScreen` returns a pointer to an object that is destroyed.  If you want to return a dynamic-length array of strings, then you are better off changing the function signature to `vector<string> getScreen(int input)`.

Answer (score 0):

In "string* getScreen( int input)" function, the "taco_burrito" is a local variable which will be stored in stack. So it will be destoried when thread leaves, it means you can't pass it to other variable.
If you want use "taco_burrito[]" and other arrays, you can put them on top your code outside "main", maybe you want to use "constant" to make them unchangeable.
I'am agree that you don't see the cout because the cout buffer doesn't fush. You better use it ends with endl.
I'am glad if it will be helpful to you!